# Ajax post request returns success but don't insert into database laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am working on a ticketing system using laravel 5.8 and ajax.
The problem is; each time a user hits "send ticket", ajax displays the message within 'success' but the form data are never inserted into the database.

Please how can i solve this?

Below is my code.

laravel Controller:

```
public function  postCreateTicket (Request $request)
    {
        $validate = $this->validate($request, [
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validate)
        {
            $new_message = TicketMessage::create([
                'ticket_subject_id'  => $request->subject,
                'investor_id' => $request->$this->investorID(), 
                'message'     => $request->message,
            ]);

            $send_status = $new_message->save();
            if($send_status)
            {
                $message = 'Your ticket was successfully sent! We will get back to you in no time.';
                return response()->json($message);
            }else{
                echo 'Error1';
            }
        }
    }
```

Html code:

```
<form method="post" id="form-data">
                            @csrf()
                                <div class="form-group text-left x3-margin-top">
                                    <label for="subject" class="grey normal x4-margin-left">Subject</label>
                                    <select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control input-lg x4-margin-left x9-width no-radius input grey">
                                        <option value="" selected>Select Subject</option>
                                        @foreach($ticket_subject as $ticket_subjects)
                                            <option value="{{$ticket_subjects->id}}">{{strtoupper($ticket_subjects->subject)}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @if($errors->has('subject'))
                                        <span class=" x4-margin-left x10-font-size maroon">{{$errors->first('subject')}}</span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group text-left x3-margin-top">
                                    <label for="message" id="message-label" class="grey normal x4-margin-left">Message</label>
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="15" class="form-control x4-margin-left x9-width"></textarea>
                                    @if($errors->has('message'))
                                        <span class="x4-margin-left x10-font-size maroon">{{$errors->first('message')}} </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-right x4-margin-top x6-margin-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg no-radius" id="submit" type="button">
                                        Send Ticket <i class="fas fa-mail-bulk"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).on('click', '#submit', function (e){
                            $.ajax({
                                    type:'POST',
                                    url : "{{route('ticket')}}",
                                    data  : {
                                        _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
                                        ticket_subject_id: $('select[name=subject]').val(),
                                        investor_id: "{{Auth::user()->investor_id}}",
                                        message: $('textarea[name=message]').val()
                                    },
                                    dataType: 'text',
                                    beforeSend: function(){$('#message-label').text('Sending..')},
                                    success : function(data)
                                    {
                                      $('#message-label').text('Sent!');
                                      $('.subject').text('');
                                      $('.message').text('');
                                    },
                                    errors : function(data)
                                    {
                                        alert('failed');
                                    }

                                });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/investor/dashboard/ticket/create/', array(
        'as'   => 'ticket',
        'uses' => 'InvestorTicketController@getCreateTicket'
    ));

    Route::post('/investor/dashboard/ticket/create/', [
        'as'   => 'ticket',
        'uses' => 'InvestorTicketController@postCreateTicket'
    ]);
```

Comment: can you show you model file. are you using any `$fillable` or `$guarded`

Comment: Can you post your model ?

Comment: Sure!
Here @Diego Cespedes 
`code`
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TicketMessage extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function ticket_subject ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketSubject');
    }

    public function ticket_response ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketResponse');
    }
}
`code`

Comment: Yes I am @Sandeep Sudhakaran

Comment: I didn't find any `subject` key in you ajax call.

Comment: I did @Sandeep Sudhakaran
It is ticket_subject_id: $('select[name=subject]').val()

Comment: your controller validating for `subject` key I think. add a `else` for `if($validate)`  statement and try. I thing your `if` is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your model**

```
<?php namespace App; 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class TicketMessage extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'ticket_subject_id',
        'investor_id',
        'message'
    ];

    public function ticket_subject () { 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketSubject', 'ticket_subject_id'); 
    } 

    public function ticket_response () { 
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketResponse'); 
    } 
}
```

You must insert all your fields `protected $fillable` array.

**I can suggest a better function**

```
public function  postCreateTicket (Request $request)
{
    try {
        // Validate stop the execution is fields are empty
        $validate = $this->validate($request, [
            'ticket_subject_id' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        $new_message = TicketMessage::create([
            'ticket_subject_id' => $request->ticket_subject_id,
            'investor_id' => Auth::user()->investor_id,
            'message' => $request->message,
        ]);

        if (!empty($new_message)){
            $message = 'Your ticket was successfully sent! We will get back to you in no time.';
            return response()->json(['message' => $message]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                "error" => "Ticket message didn't create",
            ]);
        }

    }catch (\Exception $e) {

        // If there is any error it return a error response
        return response()->json([
            "error" => $e->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Ajax Code**

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "{{route('ticket')}}",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}"},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { ticket_subject_id: $('#subject').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        },
        beforeSend: function(){$('#message-label').text('Sending..')},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.message);
            $('#message-label').text('Sent!');
            $('#subject').val('');
            $('#message').val('');

        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried it but it still didn't work @Diego Cespedes

Comment: It seems the problem is from the ajax call.
I tried getting the value of  data.message and nothing was displayed.

Comment: It still didn't insert into the database.
Updated code gave an alert with an undefined.
@Diego Cespedes

Comment: Please PRINT the request data in your controller ==> public function  postCreateTicket (Request $request)
{ dd($request->all());  We need know if the data is arriving to the controller or not.

Comment: I didn't get any response on that @Diego Cespedes

Comment: check on your console broswer => Network tab. There you can check what return each http request to the server.

Comment: I just modified the code to show me error even if it was successful and from the error it displayed.. App control skipped the try block and went to the catch block.
error: "The given data was invalid."
Diego Cespedes

Comment: I just removed the validation in my controller
'subject'=>'required',
'message'=>'required'

ANd it worked.

Comment: I updated the validation. You can try again. Please let me know if it works now